# Updating values in selected rows in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to updates "Age" column NA values selectively based on "Pclass","Embarked","Sex" averages of Age.

I want Age values in following table to update on original data frame's matching rows.

[Group Age averages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L2V2.jpg)

[Original data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhlr.jpg)

Comment: Please provide the data using `dput` or similar, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use merge. Here is a data.table approach.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(OriginalData)
setDT(NewData)
Merge <- merge(OriginalData,NewData,on = c("sex","Pclass","Embarked"))
Merge[, Age := as.numeric(Age)]
Merge[is.na(Age), Age := age]
Merge[,.(Name,Pclass,Embarked,Age)]
#                                                  Name Pclass Embarked     Age
#1: Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)      1        C 38.0000
#2:        Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)      1        S 35.0000
#3:                              Heikkinen, Miss. Laina      3        S 26.0000
#4:                                    Moran, Mr. James      3        Q 26.7381
#5:                             Braund, Mr. Owen Harris      3        S 22.0000
#6:                            Allen, Mr. William Henry      3        S 35.0000
```

**Data**

```
OriginalData <- structure(list(Row = 1:6, PassengerId = 1:6, Survived = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Pclass = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), Name = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Allen, Mr. William Henry", "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", 
"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)", "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)", 
"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", "Moran, Mr. James"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
    "male"), class = "factor"), Age = c(22L, 38L, 26L, 35L, 35L, 
    NA), SibSp = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Parch = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Ticket = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L), .Label = c("113803", "330877", "373450", "A/5 21171", 
    "PC 17599", "STON/O2. 3101282"), class = "factor"), Fare = c(7.25, 
    71.2833, 7.925, 53.1, 8.05, 8.4583), Cabin = structure(c(NA, 
    2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("C123", "C85"), class = "factor"), 
    Embarked = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("C", 
    "Q", "S"), class = "factor"), isTrain_set = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

NewData <- structure(list(Pclass = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Embarked = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("C", "Q", "S"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), age = c(16.81818, 
19.36364, 22.85477, 24.12947, 24.33333, 26.14624, 26.7381, 27.26923, 
28.45516, 30, 30.4917, 35, 36.04545, 38.10769, 40.04762, 41.70598, 
44, 53.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18"))
```

Comment: Actually, what I want is to fill the Age,NA values in Titanic data set by averaging Age based on "Pclass","Embarked","Sex"

Comment: I think data.table was smart enough to do it automatically, but I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Ian. It is working fine. But I don't understand how that piece of code working. If you can help me to understand the code. It is really appreciated.